# How to change css code by pressing a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Goal:
When you press on the button 'ok', the id element named test2 should be display non and id element named test1 should be  display block with support of css code.

And also please take account to the color of the text that is located in the css code.

Problem:
I don't know how to solve it.

What is needed to be changed in the source code in order to achieve the goal?

Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-modal-gdh4hp?

Info:
*I'm newbie in Reactjs

Thank you!

---

index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Modal } from './modal';
import './style.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      modal: true
    };
  }

  handleCloseModal = () => {
    alert('ddd');
  };

  render() {
    const { modal } = this.state;

const non = {
  display: 'none',
  color: 'yellow'
};

const block = {
  display: 'block',
  color: 'yellow'
};

    return (
      <div>
        {modal ? (
          <Modal
            onClose={() => {
              this.setState({ modal: false });
            }}
          >
            <div id="test1" style={non}>Awesome1</div>
            <div id="test2">Awesome2</div>

            <button onClick={() => this.handleCloseModal()}>ok</button>
          </Modal>
        ) : (
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              this.setState({ modal: true });
            }}
          >
            Show modal
          </button>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

---

modal.js

```
import React from 'react';

export class Modal extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { children, onClose } = this.props;
    return (
      <div style={{position: "absolute", top: 0, left: 0, width: "100%", height: "100%", background: "gray"}} onClick={ev => onClose()}>
        <div
          style={{margin: "auto", background: "white", border: "red", width: "500px", height: "300px"}}
        onClick={ev => ev.stopPropagation()}> 
          { children }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do that :

```
ok() => {
document.getElementById('test1').style.display = 'block'

document.getElementById('test2').style.display = 'none'
}
```

Comment: I have updated with new info about text color css

Answer (score 0):

You can use state

```html
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      modal: true, 
      showBlock: "",
      showNon: "",
      color: ""

      
    };
  }

  handleCloseModal = () => {
    this.setState({showBlock: "block"});
    this.setState({showNon: "none"});
    this.setState({color: "yellow"});
    alert('ddd');
  };

  render() {
    const { modal } = this.state;


    return (
      <div>
        {modal ? (
          <Modal
            onClose={() => {
              this.setState({ modal: false });
            }}
          >
           <div id="test1" style={{display: this.state.showBlock, color: this.state.color}}>Awesome1</div>
            <div id="test2" style={{display: this.state.showNon, color: this.state.color}}>Awesome2</div>

            <button onClick={() => this.handleCloseModal()}>ok</button>
          </Modal>
        ) : (
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              this.setState({ modal: true });
            }}
          >
            Show modal
          </button>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: I have updated with new info about text color css

Comment: copy to stackblitz, it shows and hides now. What else?

Comment: What color exactly are you talking about?

Comment: made the changes, yellow color added to css

Answer (score 0):

`React` way to achieve that is to use `useRef` hook (or `createRef` for class approach):

Class approach:

```js
constructor(props) {
  this.testRef = React.createRef()
}

const toggleBlock = () => {
  testRef.current.style.display = 'block'
  testRef.current.style.color = 'yellow'
}

render() {
  return (
   <>
     <div id="test1" ref={testRef}>Awesome1</div>
     <button onclick={this.toggleBlock}>Ok</button>
   </>
  )
}
```

Hooks approach:

```js
const testRef = useRef(null)

const toggleBlock = () => {
  testRef.current.style.display = 'block'
  testRef.current.style.color = 'yellow'
}


return (
   <>
     <div id="test1" ref={testRef}>Awesome1</div>
     <button onclick={this.toggleBlock}>Ok</button>
   </>
)
```